# Power Series Solution to DE

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to understand a page in my book but it skips a few steps. The book states:

$$y(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$$ solves the DE $y'' - 2zy' +\lambda y = 0$

and further $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}(n(n-1) - 2z^2n+\lambda z^2)a_nz^n=0$
$$\therefore n(n-1)a_n - 2(n-2)a_{n-2}+\lambda a_{n-2} = 0$$

When I try to derive this relationship I get something quite different:

$$y = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_nz^n = \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}a_{n-2}z^{n-2}$$
$$y' = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}na_nz^{n-1} = \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}(n-1)a_{n-1}z^{n-2}$$
$$y'' = \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_nz^{n-2}$$

Plugging these into the DE

$$\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}[n(n-1)a_n-2(n-1)a_{n-1}z + \lambda a_{n-2}]z^n = 0$$
$$\implies n(n-1)a_n-2(n-1)a_{n-1}z + \lambda a_{n-2} = 0$$

Which is already quite different from what my book has. Anyways, The only way for this to become zero is for $a_{n-1} = 0$ And now I get something completely different.

EDIT: The book states $a_n = \frac{2(n-2) -\lambda}{n(n-1)}a_{n-2}$ for $n >=2$
I do not get this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the calculation by looking at the first few terms explicitly.

$$ \eqalign{y &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n = a_0 + a_1 z + a_2 z^2 + \ldots \cr
            y' &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n a_n z^{n-1} = a_1 + 2 a_2 z + 3 a_3 z^2 + \ldots \cr           
            z y' &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n a_n z^n = a_1 z + 2 a_2 z^2 + \ldots \cr
            y'' &= \sum_{n=2}^\infty n (n-1) a_n z^{n-2} = 2 a_2 + 6 a_3 z + 12 a_4 z^2 + \ldots \cr
                &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+2)(n+1) a_{n+2} z^n\cr
    y'' - 2 z y' + \lambda y &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( (n+2)(n+1) a_{n+2} - 2 n a_n + \lambda a_n\right) z^n \cr
   &= (2 a_2 + \lambda a_0) + (6 a_3 + (-2+\lambda) a_1) z + (12 a_4 + (-4 + \lambda) a_2) z^2 + \ldots \cr}$$

Answer (score 0):

Plugging these into the DE

$$\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}[n(n-1)a_n-2(n-2)a_{n-2} + \lambda a_{n-2}]z^{n-2} = 0$$
$$\implies n(n-1)a_n-2(n-2)a_{n-2} + \lambda a_{n-2} = 0$$,

when you multiplies $y'$ for z the term $(n-2)a_{n-2}z^{n-3}$ change  to $(n-2)a_{n-2}z^{n-2}$ and the term  $(n-1)a_{n-1}z^{n-2}$ change to  $(n-1)a_{n-1}z^{n-1}$ and this last term do not compare